# Python SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Tags: python, system-error

I want to use this Batch to download Udemy videos
I wrote everything correct (I think, but there's a problem) with some kind of `systemError`.

The picture shows the error:

[image]

Comment: what that mean? I have zero knowledge.

Comment: I was following this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwqC4RrU-AY

Comment: If I were you, I'd move your script _outside_ the `C:\Python34` path.

Comment: would you mind editing your question and copying and pasting the full `import` section of the file c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\udemy_dl\udemy_dl.py

Comment: Check out the issue listing, it appears that you are running into the same issue seen here : https://github.com/gaganpreet/udemy-dl/issues/46
Do you have a udemy_dl script in c:\Python34\Scripts\ ?

Answer (score 1):

**I found the solution**

Instead of calling:

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\udemy_dl\udemy_dl.py
```

Call

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\udemy-dl
```

and it should work!